# Configuring MSSQL Server on ubuntu - Cannot open or read the persistent registry: \SystemRoot\security.hiv

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using the following guide to install MSSQL server on my ubuntu 16.04 machine
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017

when I'm running:

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

no matter what kind of SQL Server edition I choose, I'm getting the following error:

```
    Confirm the SQL Server system administrator password: 
Configuring SQL Server...

This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Mon Apr  1 16:06:07 2019
The following diagnostic information is available:

       Reason: 0x00000007
      Message: Cannot open or read the persistent registry: \SystemRoot\security.hiv.
      Process: 19600 - sqlservr
       Thread: 19604 (application thread 0x4)
  Instance Id: 7ebfcf27-db60-460d-afd3-6d852b70069e
     Crash Id: d99ba388-d323-43f3-b758-e116f42bb2e8
  Build stamp: 70437f6583b8ef39b1ef70539ef84690980315dc7a4436c9c40015f28610e4aa
 Distribution: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
   Processors: 8
 Total Memory: 16673366016 bytes
    Timestamp: Mon Apr  1 16:06:07 2019

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Capturing core dump and information to /var/opt/mssql/log...
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
      turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
      turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
/usr/bin/tail: cannot open '/var/log/syslog' for reading: Permission denied
Attempting to capture a dump with paldumper
Captured a dump with paldumper
Core dump and information are being compressed in the background. When
complete, they can be found in the following location:
  /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.04_01_2019_16_06_07.19600.tbz2
Initial setup of Microsoft SQL Server failed. Please consult the ERRORLOG
in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.
```

[also I found this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1416988/ms-sql-on-ubuntu-18-04-configuration-setup?rq=1), which look like this guy had a similar problem, but sadly no solution

does any one knows how to solve my problem?

Thank you

Edit:
after implementing the answer I got another error:

```
Confirm the SQL Server system administrator password: 
Configuring SQL Server...

Initial setup of Microsoft SQL Server failed. Please consult the ERRORLOG in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information
```

To make some clean in the mess that I had in the log folder I decided to delete it completely using

> sudo rm -rf /var/opt/mssql/log

and re-run the setup, Apparently that solved my last problem and finally:
 **Setup has completed successfully. SQL Server is now starting.**

Comment: You're in luck - i had the same problem, and I found the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll find further information in

```
/var/opt/mssql/log
```

Mine said:

```
{
    "reason": "0x00000007",
    "processName": "sqlservr",
    "pid": "5773",
    "instanceId": "d7df749c-50e6-4f3b-b894-2aa7c743f33d",
    "crashId": "281e772a-5946-4349-aa9e-671cd0a3772c",
    "threadId": "5777",
    "libosThreadId": "0x4",
    "buildStamp": "70437f6583b8ef39b1ef70539ef84690980315dc7a4436c9c40015f28610e4aa",
    "message": "Cannot open or read the persistent registry: \\SystemRoot\\lsa.hiv.",
    "last_errno": "13",
    "last_errno_text": "Permission denied",
    "distribution": "Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS",
    "processors": "4",
    "total_memory": "16732037120",
    "timestamp": "Fri Apr 12 22:02:44 2019"
}
```

So I ran locate to see where "systemroot" is located:

> locate security.hiv 
>  
>   /var/opt/mssql/.system/system/security.hiv

I didn't know which permissions should be applied, so I just gave read&write to "others".

then the same with

```
lsa.hiv
licensing.hiv
```

re-run

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

and then, sql-server starts, plus the permissions for others are gone again.

By the way, you can run sql-server without service, then it works even if the service fails:

```
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case (@Mine) it was not only licensing.hiv.
My /var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id was somehow destroyed and there were more files with owner root.
After deleting /var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id and changing all root.root files to mssql.mssql (chown mssql.mssql /var/opt/mssql/.system/system/*), I was able to rerun "/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup"
Afterwards mssql runs fine again

I very goog hint was that "/var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id" runs on his own.

Comment: Deleting the .system/instance_id and .system/.instance_id.swp files and re-running fixed it for me. not sure if there's any bad repercussions of this but for my purposes it was no issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had this error:

PalInstanceId: Unable to read instance id from file.
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: PAL initialization failed. Error: 101

Initial setup of Microsoft SQL Server failed. Please consult the ERRORLOG

Then I had to delete instance_id from "/var/opt/mssql/.system/instance_id"  and ran again mssql-conf, this works to me.

Comment: This reads like a different question, and then an answer to that question. You can post a new question, if you like, and then answer it yourself.